# save current tab in variable chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to save the current - active tab's url in a variable in my popup chrome extension.

Tried a few different methods but wondering if their was generic "save url as variable" script?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the popup, you can use the [`"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), giving you full access to the current active tab.

From there it is, unsurprisingly, the use of [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs):

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
   var currentURL = tabs[0].url;
   // You can use currentURL here..
});
// But not here, as that function is asynchronous
```